# Positioning issues with Apple devices and Safari

Tags: android, html, css, ios, progressive-web-apps

When i use the mobile version of the app on apple devices or it's web browser my button moves instead of being at the bottom part of the div

**HTML:**

```
<div id="RightContainer" class="ReportContainer">
            <section class="reportSidePanel">

                <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment activeReportPanel" id="RTabContent" data-tab="Report">
                    <div class="ui styled accordion" id="report_accordion">
                        <div id="normal-case-report">
                            <p class="normal-case-report-content">No fracture present.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blue ui buttons submitButtonWrapper">
                        <button class="ui disabled button" id="report-submission-button">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blue ui buttons submitButtonWrapper" id="nextButtonWrapper">
                        <button class="ui button next_button" id="next_button" style="display: block !important;">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blue ui buttons submitButtonWrapper" id="resultsButtonWrapper">
                        <button class="ui button" id="results_button">See results</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  #report_accordion {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.submitButtonWrapper {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[How it looks on  iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30NS4.png)

[How it looks on my android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC0Js.png)

Comment: A significant portion of the HTML code is missing. Please, provide the complete HTML code for that page.

Comment: Sorry i didn't check it twice, on my way

Comment: There are some things that need my server to be placed like answer buttons